# Should I have a separate controller for my REST methods?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a Java web application and currently I have two controllers.

One controller for REST calls and the other controller to pass ModelAndView (using Spring MVC) objects to a view.

My concern is that both of these methods are referencing the same service layer calls. Should I perhaps create an abstract class that contains the code that interacts with the service layer?

Should the REST controller be merged in with the other controller?

Comment: I would merge it since, as you said, they share the same service layer dependencies and interact on presumably the same data-model entities.

Comment: I would not merge them because it seems likely that each will have a separate client base.  Your controllers are the interface by which some client accesses the functionality of your site.  It makes sense, to me, to implement two different interface techniques (rest and MVC) with different classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make sure that none of the logic is in the controller. The controller should only get a request, call another method (which is in the service layer - a lower layer than the API layer) and return the data in the suitable format.

So for example:

```
public class MyServiceLayer() {
   public List<SomeObject> getAllSomeObjects() {
     // Do some logic to get the object back
   }
}
```

And then you can have a controller like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceLayer myService;

    // Put annotation for getting it in Json
    public List<SomeObject> getAllSomeObjectsInJson() {
        return myService.getAllSomeObjects();
    }

    // Put annotation for getting the view data
    public ModelAndView getAllSomeObjectsView() {
       // Return your ModelAndView here.
    }
}
```

In that case you can also split it to 2 controllers if you'd prefer it this way.

Anyway you should not have 2 controllers with duplicated code - that's bad! And you shouldn't be enforced to combine 2 different controllers into one. That's why you should take the logic out to a different, packed, layer.

Also this way you follow the "do one thing principle" which says that a class should have one purpose. In that case `MyServiceLayer` has one purpose - to handle the logic of getting the objects. The controller layer has one purpose - communicate the data (in which ever format you want).
If tomorrow you want to add, for example, a JMX API you won't have to duplicate your code or extend the original controller. Just add another class for handling JMX calls and uses `MyServiceLayer`

Comment: I guess technically my controller fits this. There is no logic in either of them, just calling my service layer.

Comment: @envinyater - So I guess anyway you're on the right track and not it's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Code duplication is nearly always a sign that the code in question should be packaged up in some sort of reusable component. This is the approach I take to Spring MVC controller structure:

- Code that represents some sort of logical operation should go in a service bean. This code might reasonably be called by some other component in the system as part of its workflow, and it needs to be independently testable.
- The controller classes contain only the code needed to translate HTTP requests into system operations; in many cases, this means they just wrap single calls to service methods.
- When I am exposing both JSON and HTML views of resources on the same paths, I create an abstract controller class with the `@RequestMapping` annotations in the right place and extend it with an `@RestController` that returns a resource representation of the object in question (as from Spring HATEOAS's `ResourceSupport`), and an HTML-based one that loads up a model and view.